# Can we make existing column as primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, ddl, unique-key

I have one column name `Token` and I'm generating random numbers and saving them in token but sometimes it saves duplicate tokens so I want to make it unique.

I want to know **will it affect existing records**.

Comment: Did you use php to interact with sql?

Comment: @VitoFerrulli Yes

Answer (score 2):

If you try to add a unique constraint (or primary key constraint) to a column that contains non-unique values, the `alter` statement will just fail. You need to first update the column so all values are unique (or remove duplicates), and then alter the table.

Comment: Thank You. I think it will help me

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER table Student add primary key (studentID)
```

Use the Alter command to edit table's DDL and then add a primary key to it by specifying the column.
If the primary key already exist, then first you will have to drop it before defining another PK by -

```
ALTER table STUDENT drop CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>
```

Comment: For setting a Primary Key on a column that has duplicates, you will have to get rid of them first.

Answer (score -2):

Try doing this

```
ALTER table_namePersons ADD UNIQUE (Token);
```

After doing this if you'll try to insert a duplicate key you will have an error and catching it you can generate another token

Comment: He'd be getting errors with this, since he has duplicates already on that column